# Get reactive var from another template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a template with some nested templates in Meteor:

```
<template name="collectingTmpl">
  {{> firstTmpl}}
  {{> secondTmpl}}
</template>
```

If I set a reactive var/dict in `firstTmpl` with

```
Template.firstTmpl.events({
  'click .class-name': function(event, template) {
    template.state = new ReactiveDict;
    template.state.set('someName', 'someValue');
  }
});
```

I can get this value within the same template with

```
Template.firstTmpl.helpers({
  myValue: function() {
    Template.instance().state.get('someName');
  }
});
```

but can I also retrieve the value being set in `firstTmpl` from `secondTmpl`?

I mean something like

```
Template.secondTmpl.helpers({
  myValueFromAnotherTmpl: function() {
    Template.firstTmpl.state.get('someName');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively set the `ReactiveDict` on the parent template which is `collectingTmpl`.

```
// always initialize your template instance properties
// in an onCreated lifecycle event
Template.collectingTmpl.onCreated(function(){
  this.firstTmplState = new ReactiveDict();
});
```

Then you can obtain references to this template instance property in child templates using this code :

```
Template.firstTmpl.onCreated(function(){
  // warning, this line is depending on how many parent templates
  // the current template has before reaching collectingTmpl
  var collectingTmplInstance = this.view.parentView.templateInstance();
  this.firstTmplState = collectingTmplInstance.firstTmplState;
});

Template.secondTmpl.onCreated(function(){
  var collectingTmplInstance = this.view.parentView.templateInstance();
  this.firstTmplState = collectingTmplInstance.firstTmplState;
});
```

Then you can use the standard `Template.instance().firstTmplState` syntax in any of your 3 templates and they'll always point to the same `ReactiveVar` instance defined as a property of `collectingTmpl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take care on a currently issue of blaze (missing data context), you are able to access other templates vars by Template.parentData().

See this MeteorPad as a demo, the background color will be changed onn each player when pressing the button. the color is defined by their parent template:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/zoiAvwuT3XXE5ruCf/Leaderboard_Template_parentData_Bug

You may also read at GitHub PullRequest about some updates I suggest

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/4797

Cheers
Tom